# Display x-axis as legend in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a column bar graph on google spreadsheet(created by javascript api). The code used to create the graph is

```
  var imageSheetChart = imageSheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
     .addRange(imageSheet.getRange("A1:B10"))
     .setOption('title', "Image")
     .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0).asColumnChart().setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
     .build();
  imageSheet.insertChart(imageSheetChart);
```

Below is the generated column graph.[image]

I want to generate the below graph, but I am not able to find the appropriate option for the same in javascript api. Basically, I want to enable the "Switch rows/columns" on the spreadsheet through js api.
[image]